# How to open an activity when an Ad is on frequency capping

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I use Google Admob. I have some buttons and when you click on there is an interstitial ad that is opening.
The problem is that I set in the Google Admob console a limitation (1 pub every 3 minutes) and in the code, I don't know how to handle this. Will the Ad load even if the user has already clicked on the button before 3 minutes passed? Or the ad will not load and call onAdFailedToLoad() and so I call my Intent in this method?

Actually, I put my Intent in onAdClosed(), which permits the user to open activity when he clicks on the close ad.
But if he clicks again in the buttons before 3 minutes passed?
I can't actually try because google mentioned that you must use TestAd while testing your application.

Edit:

So I discovered that the ad don't load when the frequency cap is reached. But I don't know how to handle this in my code because I set a frequency of 1 Ad every 3 minutes.
So the Ad need to load every 3 minutes.

Comment: Maybe you can use a boolean variable as a flag, then handler.postDelay() to change the flag after 3 minutes. 
Also, no need to over-worry about using your real Ad code for testing. Google will not mind if you only test it a few times. Actually, I found that if I open my app with real Ad code in Android Studio emulator, the Ad will be labelled as "Test Ad". I guess this means AdMob now automatically checks whether you are in the testing stage so it is not considered abusing or cheating.

Comment: Thank you. Okay I will use emulator so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I put this following code :

```
 if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //reload ad
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            Intent intent ....

}
```

Each time the user click on button the ad will try to load.